# How do you iterate over Mongoose model properties within a middleware function?

Tags: javascript, loops, mongoose

I'm attempting to iterate over fields in a mongoose model within a middleware function. The current context `this` is the model object itself. So I have a function in which the context is a Javascript object like this:

```
{
  lastName: 'Wilkens',
  firstName: 'Elepart',
  name: 'Elepart Wilkens',
  username: 'eK',
  bio: '<script>alert(\'this is a hack!!\')',
  _id: 53b17dd0e8c5af50c1d73bc6,
  language: 'en',
  country: 'USA',
  online: true
}
```

I want to iterate over this object (which is represented in the current function with `this`). Every time I attempt to iterate with loops, it prints out values that look like internal Javascript metadata. Is it possible to iterate over `this` within a function if `this` represents an object?

Here's the actual middleware function:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log(this); // This prints precisely the same object I have copied above

    var fields = Object.keys(this);

    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        console.log(this[fields[i]]);
    }

    for(var key in this) {
      if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(this[key]);
      }
    }
});
```

And the output is:

```
{ 
 strictMode: true,
 selected: undefined,
 shardval: undefined,
 saveError: undefined,
 validationError: undefined,
 adhocPaths: undefined,
 removing: undefined,
 inserting: undefined,
 version: undefined,
 getters: {},
 _id: undefined,
 populate: undefined,
 populated: undefined,
 wasPopulated: false,
 scope: undefined,
 activePaths: 
   { paths: 
      { username: 'modify',
        firstName: 'modify',
        name: 'modify',
        online: 'default',
        country: 'default',
        language: 'default',
        _id: 'default',
        bio: 'modify',
        lastName: 'modify' },
     states: { default: [Object], init: {}, modify: [Object], require: {} },
     stateNames: [ 'require', 'modify', 'init', 'default' ],
     map: [Function] },
  ownerDocument: undefined,
  fullPath: undefined }
true
undefined
0
{ online: true,
  country: 'USA',
  language: 'en',
  _id: 53b1825a00ed9af7c12eedf9,
  bio: '<script>alert(\'this is a hack!!\')',
  username: 'yK',
  name: 'Yershay Wilkens',
  firstName: 'Yershay',
  lastName: 'Wilkens' }
{ save: 
   [ { [Function] isAsync: false },
     { [Function: checkForExistingErrors] isAsync: false },
     { [Function: validation] isAsync: false },
     { [Function] isAsync: false },
     { [Function] isAsync: false } ],
  validate: [ { [Function] isAsync: false } ] }
{ save: [], validate: [] }
{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 }
{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 }
{}
```

Comment: Can you post the loop you are currently using?

Comment: or could you set up a fiddle ? i think it is possible

Comment: Without more code we can't help you. Though here is an example of how it could work: http://jsbin.com/gomisuyu/1/

Comment: I've added more code. A JSfiddle wouldn't be as helpful since this is all with Mongoose, so it be a bit hard to replicate in the browser.

Comment: When iterating over an object (not an array) try using "for in" `for ( key in object )` as well as `hasOwnProperty` as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: Ok, but Object.keys() returns an array if I'm not mistaken, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a slightly different way to accomplish what I wanted which was to iterate over the model properties of a Mongoose model within a middleware function. This uses [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async), but you could refactor it to use a generic JS loop or any other control flow library. The key is to get an array of the document's fields, then you can iterate over those and get/set the values using the current context with `this`. As far as I know, this will ***not*** coerce non-string values into strings. I've tested it with strings, numbers, booleans and objectIds and they are successfully saved as their original data types.

```
yourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var self = this;

  // Get the document's fields
  var fields = Object.keys(this._doc);

  // Do whatever you want for each field
  async.each(fields, function(field, cb) {
    self[field] = validator.escape(self[field]);
    cb();
  }, function(err){
    next();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using integer indexes instead of the string references from the fields array. It should be:

```
var fields = Object.keys(this);

for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    console.log(this[fields[i]]);
}
```

(e.g., you were doing `this[1]`, `this[2]`, instead of `this[fields[1]]`)

Comment: Good catch, but I just updated the question...I still get the same output, basically JS Jibberish when I do this[fields[i]]

Comment: @Glen Try changing the first line to: `var fields = Object.keys(this.toObject());`

Comment: Thanks anyways, I found that using Object.keys() with this._doc was the best way to get only the properties of the model and not all the JS stuff that I seemed to be getting by using `this` alone.

Answer (score 6):

@JohnnyHK's comment worked for me:

```
const user = new User();
const schemaKeys = Object.keys(user.toObject());
```

Comment: This should be the marked answer rather than accessing private properties via `_doc`.